# FFT in Octave/Matlab, Plot cos(x) and approximate with

Tags: matlab, fft, octave, interpolation

I have to plot in a exercise `cos(x)` in Octave and interpolate it by

[image]

I plotted cos(x) with

```
fplot("[cos(x)]", [0, 2*pi])
```

n are equidistant supporting points on `[0, 2*pi]` that I calculate by

```
x = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    x(i,1)= (-1) + (i-1/2)*(2/n);
end
```

How do I plot the term to approximate it?

Comment: Term 1 and 2 are the same in your post.

Comment: I can't see a question here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also confused about what is the question actually. I guess you want to plot that formula.

Have a row vector `k = 0:(n/2 - 1)` (suppose `n` even).

Then you need your `d` coefficients as a row vector of the same length. (I don't know from where you get them though)

Then define your **column** vector `x` (column vector is made from a row vector by transposing, e.g. `x = x.'`)

Left term of the function is then

```
leftterm = sum(d .* exp(i * x * k), 2)
```

Right term:

```
rightterm = sum( fliplr(d) .* exp(- i * x * (k.+1)), 2)
```

Alltogether they give:

```
f = sum(d .* exp(i * x * k) + fliplr(d) .* exp(- i * x * (k .+ 1)), 2)
```

and you plot it with:

```
plot(x,f)
```